# Finding volume of intersection for two cubes

Tags: 3d, language-agnostic, shapes, volume, cube

If I know that two cubes are intersecting, and I have each of their 8 vertices, and they're both parallel to the x-y, y-z, z-x planes (or aligned with the x,y,z axis). And I have the max/min x,y,z co-ordinates of each cube, how do I find the volume of intersection between them?

I tried something like

```py
if cube1_max.x > cube2_max.x: 
    x_side = abs(cube1_max.x - cube2_max.x)
```

and something similar to find y_side, z_side which are the lengths of the other two sides of the intersection cube/cuboid

So I know it has something to do with finding the difference between the x,y,z co-ordinates of each cube to get the 3 sides of the the intersection so I can then multiply then to get the volume but I'm unsure about how to go about it.

Comment: Is there any criteria for intersection i.e s can they be intersected at any angle or just vertical and horizontal ?

Comment: I guess you need to get the coordinates of the polygon created by the intersection of the cubes. You should start doing a sketch of the possible scenarios of this intersection

Comment: just vertical and horizontal, the cubes are essentially just straight, theyre not tilted,  all sides are parallel to the x-y, y-z, z-x planes

Comment: so the polygons of intersection can only be a cube or cuboid

Comment: You need overlap in *each* axis for a volume of intersection: